# LDAP DirectorySearcher with MemberOf property for user being member of ad_group1 or ad_group2 ( any group or both group )

Tags: active-directory

Current search filter for checking if the user is a member of `ad_group1`

```
&(memberOf=CN=ad_group1,OU=my_ou,DC=abc,DC=com)
```

Need to configure the search filter to check if the user is member of `ad_group1` or `ad_group2` or both the groups.

Currently the search filter is working properly for the members of group `ad_group1` .

How to expand the search filter to include the condition for the other group?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
&(|(memberOf=CN=ad_group1,OU=my_ou,DC=abc,DC=com)(memberOf=CN=ad_group2,OU=my_ou,DC=abc,DC=com))
```

The `|` operator is the logical `OR` in LDAP filters.

See [this article here](http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm) for more examples and explanations of the LDAP filter syntax.